# Demystifying HP VC-FC 4Gb Module on c7000 Chassis

Tags: cisco, hp, fibre-channel, hardware

has anyone used the HP VC-FC 4Gb Modules before in a c7000? If so could you help me understand the "Connect To" column? It shows a WWPN, but when looking at our FC switch it is connected to I don't see that WWPN in the FLOGI database...Am I missing something with these FC module?

Here is a screen shot of the VC-FC Manager
[image: VirtualConnect MGMT Console]

---

Here is our Cisco MDS, were I attempt to find the WWPN of the Module:

[image: Cisco MDS FC Switch]

Comment: Hmm. I see what you are saying Dennis, however this WWN is not the switch.. I still don't know where it is getting it from.

Answer (score 1):

That VC-FC manager screenshot is showing the WWN of a Cisco device, presumably the switch it is connected to. I haven't used FC in a C7000 yet, but my instinct says: Check the 'Server Connections' tab instead to see the local node/port WWN.

Comment: Hmm. I see what you are saying Dennis, however this WWN is not the switch.. I still don't know where it is getting it from.